# how to align text and icon inside TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox() at bottom centre in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

```
           BasicTextField(value = "India",
                onValueChange = {},
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(36.dp)
                ,
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                enabled =true,
                singleLine = true,
                textStyle = TextStyle(
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    fontSize = 15.sp,
                    ),
                decorationBox = {
                        innerTextField->
                    TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
                        value = "India",
                        innerTextField = innerTextField,
                        enabled = true,
                        singleLine = true,
                        visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
                        interactionSource = interactionSource,
                       trailingIcon = {
                           Icon(
                               imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowDropDown,
                               contentDescription = null,
                               tint = Green,
                               modifier = Modifier
                           )
                       },
                        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                            containerColor = Color.Transparent,
                            focusedIndicatorColor = Green,
                            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Green,
                            textColor = Color.Black
                        ),
                        contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp,0.dp,0.dp,0.dp)
                    )
                })
```

[image: layout with provided code]

[image: layout with provided code]

I want to align my text and icon at bottom  of the textField, even when I am changing the parameters of contentPadding, It is not making any difference and when I am wraping the TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox() inside the box then the width of TextFieldDecorationBox() is getting smaller and I want to have full width of textFieldDecoration while my text and icon inside the field to be at bottom of it (both images are same of my provided code)